# Discord selfbot не отправляет сообщение по id если диалог не начат изначально

Tags: javascript, json, requests, discord

Discord selfbot не отправляет сообщение по id если диалог не начат изначально

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js-selfbot-v13');
const { ms } = require('google-translate-api/languages');
const client = new Client(); // All partials are loaded automatically
client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} is ready!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === 'send'){ // слушает любой канал дискорда
        const userID = "id";
        client.channels.fetch(userID).then(channel=>channel.send(content));
    }
});
```

Выдает ошибку throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);

Хотя когда диалог существует с сообщением изначально, код работает без проблем

Comment: Это весь имеющийся код?

Comment: да, только вместо id(нужен ид личных сообщений участника) и вместо content в строковом значении

Comment: залогинился? Я не вижу. Если нет, то client.login('token'); Как получить токен в README к npm пакету описано.

Comment: дада именно там нужен токен  client.login('token');  все верно

Comment: Проблема в другом, бот не отправляет сообщение в лс, если диалог не начат до этого

Comment: Посмотри, как регистрировать команды, получать и отравлять сообщения в [гайде discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#registering-commands). Там все по шагам расписано. Читай, сравнивай со своим кодом.